# Test for OU-Process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose that I'm given a sample from time-series $(x_n)_{n=1}^N$ and want to decide if it comes from an OU process or not.  Is there a (rigorous) test I can use?

So far, everything I've seen is hand-wavy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\th{\theta}$ $\newcommand\Si{\Sigma}$
The Ornstein--Uhlenbeck (OU) process is a Gaussian process, with the mean and covariance functions being [known functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process#Mathematical_properties) depending on $s\le4$ unknown real-valued parameters of the OU process. So, for the sample $X:=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, we know the functions $\mu$ and $\Si$ given by $\mu(\th):=E_\th X$ and $\Si(\th):=Cov_\th X$ for all $s$-tuples $\th$ of the real-valued parameters. Then 
$$Z(\th):=\Si(\th)^{-1/2}(X-\mu(\th))$$
has the standard normal distribution in $\mathbb R^n$.

Now using appropriate estimates of $\th$ and partitioning $\mathbb R^n$ into some number $k>s+1$ of disjoint Lebesgue-measurable sets of nonzero (say the same) Gaussian measure, we can use e.g. a chi-square goodness-of-fit test,  with a test statistic distributed approximately as $\chi^2$ with $k-s-1$ degrees of freedom, as described e.g. by [Watson](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2983906).

---

Another goodness-of-fit test, based on a strict negative definiteness of Euclidean distance, is described in Section 3 of the paper by [Székely and Rizzo](http://personal.bgsu.edu/~mrizzo/energy/MVN-GOF-2005.pdf).

Comment: What is the advantages of the latter method?

Comment: In Sections 5 and 6 of their paper, Székely and Rizzo provide comparisons with a few other tests.

Comment: Thanks, Iosif.  This is very interesting and useful actually.

Comment: I am glad this helped.